# My c program crashes after it finishes running

Tags: c, compiler-construction, crash

My program will run and display info correctly but as soon as I press any key to continue I get program has stopped working screen, I don't know why, here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char A[50][30];
  printf("Hello \n");

  FILE *file;

  file = fopen("Strings.dat","r");



  printf("The contents of the array are :\n");

  int ch = 0;

  while(fgets(A[ch], 30, file))
  {
    int length = strlen(A[ch]);
    /*
  if((A[ch][length-1]) == '\n')
  {
    A[ch][length-1] = NULL;
  }
*/
  ch++;
   }
  fclose(file);
  printf("%s",A[0]);
  system("PAUSE");
}
```

Can anyone explain what I did wrong?

if you're wondering the commented code is commented out because it gave me a warning "[Warning] assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]" I thought taking it out would fix my problem

Comment: The only thing I see is that you're not checking that the file opened properly. If `file` is `NULL` then the file didn't open.

Comment: Oh good - most of my apps crash while running.

Comment: Double check the contents and size of the file you are reading.  It's possible you are writing outside the bounds of your array and smashing your stack and it manifests itself as the program ends and the stack unwinds.

Comment: Add the following line at the beginning of the `while` loop and make sure that `ch` is never more than 49. `printf( "%d\n", ch );`

Comment: @user3386109, an easier way to accomplish what I was trying to say.

Comment: @duck you are right I put in 51 string in my file instead of 50 now return 0 works

Comment: Yay! Now all we need to do is give Duck the right answer and we can all go home happy :)

Comment: @user3393513, another happy customer.  Happy computing.

Comment: @user3386109 doesn't he have to submit it as an answer for me to accept it?

Comment: Yep, that's true, so we'll just have to let it be :)

Comment: Yep, feel free to uncheck mine. Seems Duck found the CORRECT answer rather than just a workaround. Good work!

Comment: I appreciate the sentiments guys but it's no big deal.  Alls well that ends well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `exit(0);` after your pause statement. This will tell your program to exit completely. The 0 is simply a return value. You can return whatever you want, but 0 is standard for "no errors" or something like that.

EDIT: On second thought, simply add `return 0;` at the end. You may not even need the exit(0) statement (it depends on how you're running your program).

SECOND EDIT: The exit() statement simply force-closes your application. There is still an underlying issue. Give me a bit and I will try to track it down for you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Occasionally I have a similar problem when I don't tell the program to exit properly. I'm not sure if it has to do with the way the program is run or what. I usually run my C programs in a console, perhaps this only works in those cases? It couldn't hurt to try it.

Comment: yes this line of code stopped my program from crashing

Comment: Excellent, I'm very happy to hear it! I noticed your main() function is of type `int` but it does not return an int. `exit(0)` stops the program, but `return 0` should also work. If you have neither one, the program keeps waiting for an int to be returned, and when it doesn't come it becomes a resource hog and your system stops it from running (hence the error message). Try swapping out `exit(0)` with `return 0;` and see if it also works. I have a feeling it might.

Comment: It works because `exit` short circuits the stack unwinding.  The error is still there

Comment: i tried the line return 0; and the program crashed, then I tried return (0); and also resulted in a crash

Comment: In that case I'm inclined to agree with Duck. The exit statement only force-closes the application. There must be an underlying problem.

Comment: The C specification states that falling off the end of `main` is the same as returning 0 from `main`. And returning 0 from main has the same effect as calling exit(0) at the end of `main`.  The only difference is that calling `exit` short circuits the stack unwinding. The error is still there.

Comment: I am not seeing where you check for the end of the file? Put the following inside the `while()` statement: `if( feof(file) ){ break ; }`

Comment: `fgets` returns `NULL` at the end-of-file, and breaks the loop.

Comment: Ahh, I see now. I was picturing fgetc

Comment: Problem solved, @duck mentioned that I should double check my file and noticed I put one too many stings, now return 0 works